# Python random sample with exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, random

I'm attempting to create a sample of `myList` with the exception of `i_`.

My Attempt:

```
i_ = 'd'

myList = ['a','b','c','d','e']

myList = random.sample(myList, 3)
```

Although the above sample works fine, there is still a chance that `i_` is removed from `myList`.

I would like to create a sample without the value of `i_` being removed.

***Desired Output:***

Any list output containing 3 items including `i_`, e.g:

```
['a','d','e']
```

Comment: That's not what random is designed for. What you could do is something like `[_i] + random.sample(myList, 3)` which will ensure `_i` is in your list, or just keep generating lists until you find `_i` somewhere in one.

Comment: Could you just remove i_ from your initial list before drawing a sample and then add it manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just sample 2 values from the list without the `i_` and insert `i_` later:

```
new_list = random.sample([i for i in myList if i != i_], 2)
new_list.insert(random.randrange(0, 3), i_)
```

But this assumes that `i_` occurs only once in your list - seems reasonable given your example but I wanted to mention this for completeness. Also I'm not sure what the desired result should be if there were multiple `i_` in the list.

---

You could also use a hit&miss approach that generates a sample until you get one that contains `i_`:

```
new_list = []
while i_ not in new_list:
    new_list = random.sample(myList, 3)
```

Note that this could be really slow if it's unlikely that `i_` is drawn in the sample. For a 3-sample of 5 elements it's quite fast but it could be *really slow* if you draw a 3-sample from 1000 elements.

Comment: On second thoughts it doesn't seem to work, I'm getting the error:     new_list.insert(i_, random.randrange(0, 3))
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: @LearningToPython Thanks for bringing that up. I had the arguments swapped. :( It's fixed now

Comment: Ah, Okay! Thank You =)

Answer (score 2):

Guarantee that `i_` will be in the list, then take one fewer random element.

```
myList.remove(i_)
myList = random.sample(myList, 2)
myList.append(i_)
```

You can combine these into one line if you wish.

Comment: The downside of this being, `i_` is always at the end of the random sample.

Comment: If that's an issue, simply insert it in a random place.

Answer (score 0):

if a "one liner" is wanted then you can inline slice `i_` out of `myList` and take 2 random samples, add `i_` and 'shuffle' that inline with `sample(x, k=len(x))` from the docs

written with line breaks

```
i_ = 'd'

myList = ['a','b','c','d','e']

random.sample(random.sample(myList[:myList.index(i_)] +
                            myList[(myList.index(i_) + 1):],
                             2)
              + [i_], k=3)

['c', 'd', 'b']
```